# HTML, CSS - HOVER для элементов из разных блоков

Tags: html, css, hover

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы при наведении на любой из элементов с классом `row-1` менялся фон одновременно у всех элементов с классом `row-1`.
Это маленькая табличка из `div-ов`.

Задача: при наведении на столбец ***`любую ячейку столбца`*** должен загораться весь столбец.

Возможно ли это?

Подскажите как?

```css
.table-stu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  max-width: 700px;
}

.row-table-stu {
  display: flex;
}

.row-table-stu div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 46px;
  text-align: center;
}

.row-table-stu div:first-child {
  min-width: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.row-table-stu div:last-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.table-stu .row-table-stu:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.table-stu-price-descr {
  font-size: 12px;
  max-width: 700px;
}

.row-table-stu:first-child div:first-child {
  border-radius: 8px 0 0 0;
}

.row-table-stu:first-child div:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 8px 0 0;
}

.row-table-stu:last-child div:first-child {
  border-radius: 0 0 0 8px;
}

.row-table-stu:last-child div:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 0 8px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-stu">
  <div class="row-table-stu">
    <div class="row-1">Lorem1</div>
    <div class="row-2">Lorem2</div>
    <div class="row-3">Lorem3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-table-stu">
    <div class="row-1">Lorem1</div>
    <div class="row-2">Lorem2</div>
    <div class="row-3">Lorem3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-table-stu">
    <div class="row-1">Lorem1</div>
    <div class="row-2">Lorem2</div>
    <div class="row-3">Lorem3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Скорее всего Вам придется использовать JavaScript для этого, либо формировать таблицу по столбцам, а не по строкам. И да, в Вашем случае было бы неплохо поменять `row-*` классы, на `col-*`, потому что сбивает с толку.

Comment: Спасибо. Согласен.

Comment: @Bogdan, я правильно понимаю что, с точки зрения скорости загрузки сайта лучше переделать таблицу по столбцам и не использовать JavaScript?  вариант с JavaScript будет медленнее?

Comment: Повесить на элемент(ы) пару классов и снять их  - не такая уж и высокая нагрузка (к тому же эти скрипты выполняются, когда страница уже полностью загружена). Не думаю, что это как-то отразится на скорости загрузки. Гораздо ощутимее на это влияют нестандартные шрифты и несжатые изображения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данной реализации без JavaScript не обойтись. Если реализовывать средствами css, то придется переделать табличку и вместо строк объединять ячейки колонками.

**Вариант на jQuery**

```js
$('.table-stu').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
      var num = $('.row-table-stu').eq(0).find('.cell').length;
        
        for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
         if ($(this).hasClass('row-' + i)) {
           $('.row-' + i).addClass('row-hover');
          }
        }
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $('.cell').removeClass('row-hover');
    }
}, '.cell');
```

```css
.table-stu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    max-width: 700px;
}

.row-table-stu {
    display: flex;
}

.row-table-stu div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 46px;
    text-align: center;

}
.row-table-stu div:first-child {
    min-width: 100px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.row-table-stu div:last-child {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.table-stu .row-table-stu:first-child {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.table-stu-price-descr {
    font-size: 12px;
    max-width: 700px;
}
.row-table-stu:first-child div:first-child {
    border-radius: 8px 0 0 0;
}
.row-table-stu:first-child div:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 8px 0 0;
}
.row-table-stu:last-child div:first-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 0 8px;
}
.row-table-stu:last-child div:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 8px 0;
}

.row-hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="table-stu">
  <div class="row-table-stu">
    <div class="cell row-1">Lorem</div>
    <div class="cell row-2">Lorem</div>
    <div class="cell row-3">Lorem</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-table-stu">
    <div class="cell row-1">Lorem</div>
    <div class="cell row-2">Lorem</div>
    <div class="cell row-3">Lorem</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-table-stu">
    <div class="cell row-1">Lorem</div>
    <div class="cell row-2">Lorem</div>
    <div class="cell row-3">Lorem</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Вариант на CSS если переделать табличку колонками**

```css
.table {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.table-col {
  width: 33.33%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.table-col + .table-col {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
}

.table-col:hover .table-cell {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.table-cell {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.table-cell + .table-cell {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-col">
    <div class="table-cell">1</div>
    <div class="table-cell">1</div>
    <div class="table-cell">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-col">
    <div class="table-cell">2</div>
    <div class="table-cell">2</div>
    <div class="table-cell">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-col">
    <div class="table-cell">3</div>
    <div class="table-cell">3</div>
    <div class="table-cell">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Я правильно понимаю что, с точки зрения скорости загрузки сайта лучше переделать таблицу по столбцам и не использовать JavaScript?  вариант с JavaScript будет медленнее?

Comment: @RomanMolchanov
Ну медленней он не будет, там всего несколько строк кода и нет ни каких тяжелых операций, но если есть возможность реализовать тоже самое используя css, то конечно такой вариант будет лучше. По этому если расположение ячеек в строках не несет ни какой значимости, то да, лучше переделать по столбцам и использовать только css.